# My ListNode cannot return "null"

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program to find a node value in a linked list. I intended to let the program return the value when the value existed in the list and return `null` when it not existed in the list. But when I type the value(e.g. 4) that is not in the Linked List it cannot return `null`.

```
 package com.company;

    /**
     * Created by Administrator on 2016/10/20 0020.
     */
    public class find {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ListNode node1 = new ListNode(1);
            ListNode node2 = new ListNode(2);
            ListNode node3 = new ListNode(3);

            node1.next = node2;
            node2.next = node3;

            ListNode node = findNode(node1,4);
            System.out.println(node.val);

        }

        public static ListNode findNode(ListNode head, int val){
            for (ListNode node = head; node != null; node = node.next ){
                if (node.val == val){
                    return node;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class ListNode{
        int val;
        ListNode next;
        ListNode(int x){
                val = x;
                next = null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: i ran the code and got a null pointer exception so it returned null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Node node = findNode(node1,4);
    if(node == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The Node was not found in the linked list");
    }
    else
        System.out.println(node.val);
```

Add an if check so you don't run into a null pointer exception when the findNode returns null when the node doesn't exists with the desired value. Your current implementation works, I ran it and it does give back a null as designed.